# Mail in Laravel with smtp gmail

Tags: laravel, email

When I am sending with smtp.mailtrap.com everything is working, but with smtp.gmail.com I'm getting error *Connection could not be established with host smtp.gmail.com [ #0]*.
2 step verification is turned on.

```
MAIL_DRIVER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.gmail.com
MAIL_PORT=465
MAIL_USERNAME=mymail@gmail.com
MAIL_PASSWORD=app_password(16 digit)
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=ssl
```

Comment: make sure to turn off 2 step verification on your google account. https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/1064203?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en&oco=0

Comment: Dino Numić I'm tried with my actual gmail password but getting same error